# Get value attribute MIB-Table snmp

Tags: java, snmp, mib

How to get the all values of MIB-table in java? Exist an api to do this? I'm building a manage to get router counters to estimate the performance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use [snmp4j-framework](http://www.snmp4j.org/)

code example:

```
final Address targetAddress = GenericAddress.parse("X.X.X.X/80");
final TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
final Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);
snmp.listen();
final CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
target.setAddress(targetAddress);
target.setRetries(80);
target.setTimeout(1500);
target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);  
final PDUFactory pduFactory = new DefaultPDUFactory(PDU.GETBULK);
final TableUtils utils = new TableUtils(snmp, pduFactory);
return utils.getTable(target, new OID[]{ query }, null, null);
```